# Cannot compile Vue.js for IE 11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, laravel-mix

So I recently asked a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/92678500?noredirect=1) and after a lot of googling and trying things out this is what I have for my `babel.rc`:

```
{
  "presets": [["env", {
    "modules": false,
    "uglify": true,
    "targets": {
      "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
    }
  }],
  "vue",
  "vue-app",
  "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-vue-jsx"]
}
```

And this is what I have for my webpack:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
var path = require('path');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

var npm = '/node_modules/';

var paths = {
  'jquery-ui': npm + 'jquery-ui/',
  'bootstrap': npm + 'bootstrap/',
  'select2': npm + 'select2/dist/',
  'lightbox2': npm + 'lightbox2/dist/',
  'accounting': npm + 'accounting/',
  'polly-fill': npm + '@babel/polyfill/dist/',
};

var jQueryUITheme = 'ui-lightness';

mix.less('resources/assets/less/style.less', 'public/css/', {
  modifyVars: {
    'bootstrap': '"' + path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['bootstrap'] + 'less/' + '"'
  }
}).js('resources/assets/js/boot.js', 'public/js/all.js').webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "matches-selector/matches-selector": "desandro-matches-selector",
      "eventEmitter/EventEmitter": "wolfy87-eventemitter",
      "get-style-property/get-style-property": "desandro-get-style-property",
      'masonry': 'masonry-layout',
      'isotope': 'isotope-layout',
      'isotope/js/layout-mode': 'isotope-layout/js/layoutmode',
      'pace': 'pace-progress',
      "jquery-ui/ui/widget": "jquery-ui/widget.js",
    }
  },
}).js('resources/assets/js/vue/main.js', 'public/js/vue.js')
  .scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/lib/jquery.validate.min.js',
    'resources/assets/js/lib/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js',
    path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['accounting'] + 'accounting.js'
  ], 'public/js/genesis.js')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['jquery-ui'] + 'themes/' + jQueryUITheme + '/jquery-ui.min.css', 'public/css/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['jquery-ui'] + 'themes/' + jQueryUITheme + '/theme.css', 'public/css/lib/jquery-ui/theme.css')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['jquery-ui'] + 'themes/' + jQueryUITheme + '/images', 'public/css/lib/jquery-ui/images')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['select2'] + 'css/select2.min.css', 'public/css/lib/select2/select2.min.css')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['lightbox2'] + 'css/lightbox.min.css', 'public/css/lib/lightbox2/css')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['lightbox2'] + 'images/loading.gif', 'public/css/lib/lightbox2/images')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['lightbox2'] + 'images/close.png', 'public/css/lib/lightbox2/images')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['lightbox2'] + 'images/next.png', 'public/css/lib/lightbox2/images')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['lightbox2'] + 'images/prev.png', 'public/css/lib/lightbox2/images')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['polly-fill'] + 'polyfill.min.js', 'public/js/')
  .copy(path.resolve(__dirname) + '/resources/assets/js/lib/pace.js', 'public/js/')
  .sourceMaps();

 mix.babel(['public/js/main.js'], 'public/js/main.js');
 mix.babel(['public/js/vue.js'], 'public/js/vue.js');
 mix.minify(['public/js/main.js', 'public/js/vue.js', 'public/css/style.css']);
```

I **Understand ie 11 does not in any ways have support for anything above es5** how ever My vue JS is still not compiling to ES5, The output from my last question is still the same. I am confused as to how to compile Vue JS to ES5 such that I don't get the following:

The error:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
vue.js (16,8498)
```

Ok, so whats at this line?

```
(module,__webpack_exports__,__webpack_require__){"use strict";eval("/* unused harmony export getJSON */\n/* unused harmony export getScrollBarWidth */\n/* unused harmony export translations */\n/* harmony export (immutable) */ __webpack_exports__[\"b\"] = delayer;\n/* unused harmony export VueFixer */\n// coerce convert som types of data into another type\nconst coerce = {\n  // Convert a string to booleam. Otherwise, return the value without modification, so if is not boolean, Vue throw a warning.\n  boolean: val => (typeof val === 'string' ? val === '' || val === 'true' ? true : (val === 'false' || val === 'null' || val === 'undefined' ? false : val) : val),\n  // Attempt to convert a string value to a Number. Otherwise, return 0.\n  number: (val, alt = null) => (typeof val === 'number' ? val : val === undefined || val === null || isNaN(Number(val)) ? alt :
```

*I am unsure what version of webpack I am using as I am using Laravel Mix, but I am using babel 6.*

**everything compiles fine, but Vue JS still doesn't compile properly down to ES5 for IE 11.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number: (val, alt = null) => (typeof val === 'number' ? val : val === undefined.....` inside your bundle code says to me that arrow functions were not transpiled into normal functions. Try to add `transform-es2015-arrow-functions` babel plugin. If you will still experience similar errors - try to analyze the code of your bundle and find which [ES6 feature not supported by IE11](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) remain there.